# Ask Google Home Assistant to run CURL commands

Tags: c#, curl, google-assistant-sdk

I cannot find a way to ask my Google Home Assistant to run cURL commands for me. Ideally this process is achieved through services linked together only but a script would do also; my language of preference is C#. I'd then convert the C# code to python and put on rpi.

I have tried using IFTTT webhooks, zapier and was looking into google assistant sdk but it seems that the process/setup is way too complex to achieve such a simple task.

Any easier ways to do this please?

Comment: That did not help me much but expected, apologies. I just wish someone could give me a sample or direct me in the right direction. thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [command_line switch](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/switch.command_line/) or a [shell command](https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/shell_command/)? You should be able to execute both as part of an automation.